# How do I make NodeJS applications scalable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, architecture, restful-architecture

I am designing a chat application in NodeJS using express, mongo db, socket io. What points should I keep in focus while designing the architecture for this application. The target audience for this app is going to be more then 50K users concurrently using it.

I have previously in my career designed apps that were used by 2k end users at max. But this is something new for me. I did a lot of research on it and came up with the following points.

1- Start using queuing services like RabbitMQ 
   2- Increase your server space/ram as the usage increases.

Can someone please point me in the write direction a book on NodeJS architecture patterns and scalability. A guide, a walk through any sort of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Here some tips:**

You should take a look at the [Cluster module](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) you can also use [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk) for HTTP benchmark.

Make sure you use caching.

If you are using Docker you should use the [swarm mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/).

Use Amazon Elastic https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/

Comment: Just a little addition - while working with multiple instances you need to think how you want to handle session management - so other workers may have access to session if load balancer redirect traffic to them. I am working with session stored in Redis - work like a charm - you may use packages express-session and connect-redis.